# Was Adam really "alone" if God took 'Woman out of Man'? Is a woman alone if out of her womb 'a new one' comes?

Tags: genesis, creation, adam-and-eve

Texts (from the [Complete Jewish Bible](https://www.biblegateway.com/versions/Complete-Jewish-Bible-CJB/) translation):

[Genesis 2:18](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis+2%3A18&version=CJB) (CJB):

> *ADONAI*, God, said, “It isn’t good that the person should be alone. I will make for him a companion suitable for helping him.”

[Genesis 2:21-22](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis+2%3A21-22&version=CJB) (CJB):

> Then God caused a deep sleep to fall upon the person; and while he was sleeping, he took one of his ribs and closed up the place from which he took it with flesh. The rib which *ADONAI*, God, had taken from the person, he made a woman-person; and he brought her to the man-person.

Was the first man really "alone" if God took the woman out of the man's side? Likewise: is a woman alone, since out of her side (womb) a new creation will come?

I am mainly interested in answers from Biblical Creationists.

Comment: Adam was alone, with all his ribs intact. Then he slept, and when he awoke, he was no longer alone. I don't see why this should be difficult to appreciate, myself. The New Creation comes with the revelation of the Son of God. (It does not come out of the side of a woman.)

Comment: "It is not good for the man to be alone".  If he was not alone then this statement makes no sense.

Answer (score 4):

I'm a bit perplexed by this question, but here goes ...

Genesis 18, 21-22

> "Yahweh God also said, “It is not good for the man to be alone. I will
> make for him a suitable helper.” [...] 21 So Yahweh God caused the man
> to fall into a deep sleep, and while he slept, He took one of the
> man’s ribs and closed up the area with flesh. 22 And from the rib that
> the Yahweh God had taken from the man, He made a woman and brought her
> to him."

The OP asks

> "Was The First Man Really 'ALONE' ... if God Took The Woman Out of The
> Man's side?"

It's pretty clear from the Genesis quote that what is taken out of the man's side isn't a woman, but a rib. That rib then was made into a woman.

Regardless, Adam's rib wasn't a 'suitable helper', it was a rib. It is in this sense that Adam is alone (when Eve is created, there are other creatures as well as Adam, but he is still alone in the relevant sense).

Answer (score 1):

It would be meaningful to have a look at  Gen 1:21-22:

> And God created great whales, and every living creature that moveth, which the waters brought forth abundantly, after their kind, and every winged fowl after his kind: and God saw that it was good.  And God blessed them, saying, Be fruitful, and multiply, and fill the waters in the seas, and let fowl multiply in the earth

And go on to read Gen 1:27-28:

> So God created man in his own image, in the image of God created he him; male and female created he them. And God blessed them, and God said unto them, Be fruitful, and multiply, and replenish the earth, and subdue it: and have dominion over the fish of the sea, and over the fowl of the air, and over every living thing that moveth upon the earth.

So, what is meant by being alone is that Adam initially had no female companion through whom he could bring forth  his progeny -- until Eve was created.  Of course, he could  have remained immortal and single. But, having been a creation of bones and flesh, he would have to return to the mud from where he had come (Gen 3:19), so that the progeny would take over through a continuous  mechanism of invigoration.

Answer (score -3):

The story in Gen. 1 gives a very different account from Gen. 2. This is actually stipulated in the text. After the Gen. 1 story concludes, the Garden of Eden story begins:

> This is the account of the heavens and the earth when they were
> created, when the Lord God made the earth and the heavens. (Gen. 2:4)

(*Note: the above can also be read as a summary of Gen. 1, but either way, it  serves to distinguish the two accounts.*)

**The two accounts**

In Gen. one there is no "Adam," there are two unnamed human beings, male and female, created in God's image. They are created on the Sixth Day after the vegetation and animals. In Gen. 2, Adam is formed from the dust prior to the vegetation, and Eve is not yet mentioned.

> Now no shrub had yet appeared on the earth and no plant had yet sprung
> up, for the Lord God had not sent rain on the earth and there was no
> one to work the ground, but streams came up from the earth and watered
> the whole surface of the ground.  Then the Lord God formed a man from
> the dust of the ground and breathed into his nostrils the breath of
> life, and the man became a living being.

I point this out because I think these are two different stories by two different authors and it is a misstep, hermeneutically, to combine them as if they were one.  For a summary of the basis for the idea of dual authorship see [Documentary Hypothesis](https://www.cs.umd.edu/%7Emvz/bible/doc-hyp.pdf). (*Note: this does not preclude IMO that both stories were inspired by God, only that it is a mistake to treat them as if they are one account*.)

**Was Adam alone?**

Since the OP asks, however, I will point out that Adam as *BOTH* male and female is a very old concept. An article in the Jewish publication [Forward](https://forward.com/community/356899/was-adam-a-hermaphrodite/) points out:

> The rabbis understood this to mean that Adam was created as an
> intersexed being, a hermaphrodite; singular in one respect, plural in
> another. Exactly how Adam was constituted as an intersexed being was
> debated. Rabbi Jeremiah ben Elazar held that Adam was an androgyne,
> while Rabbi Samuel bar Nachman held that Adam was more like conjoined
> male/female twins.

So **if Rabbi Samuel is correct, Adam was not alone.** However, the text itself does not indicate this. In fact it depicts God as saying "It is not good that then man should be alone."

As long was were are entertaining speculation, there is also a Jewish legend that Adam had a previous wife, before Eve, namely [Lilith](https://jwa.org/encyclopedia/article/lilith). She did not like playing a subordinate role, either sexually or otherwise, and left him. If we include this legend, Adam was currently "alone," but he had not always been so. However, once again, this has to be considered speculation.

**To take the OP question on directly: Adam was not alone in Gen. 1, but he was alone in Gen. 2, whether Eve was part of him or not.**

Comment: The first account is the 'Elohim'account. It is the spirituality of creation, as such, that is to say the purposed creation. The second account is the 'Jehovah' creation. If unbelief merely dismisses these accounts ('dual' authorship etc etc) then the reader will simply miss the depth of profundity, the sheer spirituality, of what is written.

Comment: It is not unbelief, nor does it dismiss the accounts. For me, it is no more "unbelief' than saying there is more than one psalmist, or that one dismisses the proverbs because one thinks that some of the ones attributed to Solomon were not actually written by him.